# Android SQLite ordering table columns differently

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm setting up an SQLite Database and I've got most things set up how I think they're supposed to be. The main error has to with a column not being where it should be. I initialized the database column names in strings like so:

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_SPORT = "given_sport";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "given_name";
public static final String KEY_DATE = "given_date";
public static final String KEY_TIME = "given_time";
public static final String KEY_PERIOD = "given_period";
public static final String KEY_LOCATION = "given_location";
```

When it was time to create a table with the column names:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + 
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                KEY_SPORT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_TIME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_PERIOD + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_LOCATION + "TEXT NOT NULL);"
);
```

The problem now is that I'm getting the following error:

`05-27 04:13:01.448: E/Database(273): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table groupTable has no column named given_location: , while compiling: INSERT INTO groupTable(given_location, given_time, given_date, given_period, given_sport, given_name) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);`

It seems like the table names are being reordered and that's what is causing the error in insertion. I'm clueless though and I'd really appreciate some help with this.

**EDIT: here's the INSERT command**

```
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_SPORT, sportInput);
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, nameInput);
    cv.put(KEY_DATE, dateInput);
    cv.put(KEY_TIME, timeInput);
    cv.put(KEY_PERIOD, periodInput);
    cv.put(KEY_LOCATION, locationInput);
    return dbSQL.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that you've changed the database structure but not the database version. It's a weird issue that I had to spend a lot of time figuring out the first time.

In your DatabaseHelper class there should be a version number, just increment it by one anytime you change any table schema etc.

EDIT

You're missing a space before the "TEXT" in your SQL table creation.

It should be:

...
+ KEY_LOCATION+ " TEXT" ...

once you fix that, increment the version number again.

Comment: @Sam, I'm sure if I had made that mistake myself I would have spent hours looking for it. :)

Comment: Wow. I feel dumb. Fixed it though, and I had to change the version. Kinda annoying to have to do that all the time. But thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

The order of the table columns will not create "no column" error. If you have added the column to your table after running your app at least once but haven't incremented the *database version*, this is one way to cause this error.

The order of these columns:

```
INSERT INTO groupTable(given_location, given_time, given_date, given_period, given_sport, given_name) ...
```

depends on the order of the columns when you write your `INSERT` statement, it is not a fixed order based off of the `CREATE` command.

Comment: I got this error the first time I ran it. After, I renamed all the columns thinking it might be some sort of name conflict thing. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Saw your edit. Edited the post with the insert command. I used ContentValues to do this, so maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: Yes (to your first comment). If you change the Java / Android code you need to drop the table and create it again to change the SQLite database. The easiest way to do this is to increment the database version.

Comment: (To your second comment) Using a ContentProvider and the order of the columns in the ContentProvider will not cause your error, your code looks good.

Comment: I updated the version number, which I'm assuming calls onUpgrade() which I have all the drop table stuff in. No change.

Comment: Please post your `SQLiteOpenHelper` class with the constructor, `onCreate()`, and `onUpgrade()` functions. Let's see what's going on.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but its a simple error I overlooked. Look at you786's post. Sorry, sorta wasted your time.